# Changing the hot key for run selection in Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, hotkeys

I'm not sure what is the best approach for asking these question, so I'm putting them all together here.  After some googling these questions didn't have an obvious answer.

1) In Powershell ISE is there a way to change the "run selection" quick-key/hot-key so that it's something other than the default (which is F8)?

2) For that matter, is there a way to add quick-key bindings without adding a menu?

3) Can one add key cords to the ISE like in Visual Studio (Ctrl-d, Ctrl-h) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can *change*, but you can *add* another key to do the same:

```
function invoke-selection
{
    iex $psISe.CurrentFile.Editor.SelectedText
}
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Run selection",{invoke-selection},'f7')
```

Add the above to your Powershell ISE profile - `$profile` from ISE

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer in no.

Unfortunately the ISE is a very basic editor and doesn't provide much in the way of customisation.

This might change when the ISE for PSv3.0 is released.

In the mean time this post has a list of PowerShell ISEs that you might want to try:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171514/best-ide-for-powershell

regards
Arcass

Comment: That link is now broken, presumably because such lists are off-topic for SO.